# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDevelopDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am getting build errors and am not able to resolve them.
Need help

Here is my **stacktrace**:

```
> E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:22:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.idware.uss.DataBase.DBModels.Notification> p0);
>                                                                                           ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:21:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLastNotification(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:21:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLastNotification(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:27:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer> p0);
>                                                               ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:26:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getNotificationCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:26:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getNotificationCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:13:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
>                                                         ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:11:
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object insertNotification(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:18:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer> p0);
>                                                               ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:17:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getBaseConfigCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:17:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getBaseConfigCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:23:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.idware.uss.DataBase.DBModels.BaseConfigurations> p0);
>                                                                                                 ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:22:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLatestBaseConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:22:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLatestBaseConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:27:
> error: Not sure how to handle query method's return type
> (java.lang.Object). UPDATE query methods must either return void or
> int (the number of updated rows).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object updateBaseConfigurationsEmail(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:30:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p2);
>                                                         ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:27:
> error: Unused parameter: p2
>     public abstract java.lang.Object updateBaseConfigurationsEmail(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:13:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
>                                                         ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:11:
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object insertBaseConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:18:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer> p0);
>                                                               ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:17:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getAppConfigCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:17:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getAppConfigCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:23:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.idware.uss.DataBase.DBModels.AppConfigurations> p0);
>                                                                                                ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:22:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLatestAppConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:22:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLatestAppConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:13:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
>                                                         ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\developDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:11:
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object insertAppConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:22:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.idware.uss.DataBase.DBModels.Notification> p0);
>                                                                                           ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:21:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLastNotification(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:21:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLastNotification(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:27:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer> p0);
>                                                               ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:26:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getNotificationCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:26:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getNotificationCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:13:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
>                                                         ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\NotificationsDao.java:11:
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object insertNotification(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:18:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer> p0);
>                                                               ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:17:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getBaseConfigCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:17:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getBaseConfigCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:23:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.idware.uss.DataBase.DBModels.BaseConfigurations> p0);
>                                                                                                 ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:22:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLatestBaseConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:22:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLatestBaseConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:27:
> error: Not sure how to handle query method's return type
> (java.lang.Object). UPDATE query methods must either return void or
> int (the number of updated rows).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object updateBaseConfigurationsEmail(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:30:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p2);
>                                                         ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:27:
> error: Unused parameter: p2
>     public abstract java.lang.Object updateBaseConfigurationsEmail(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:13:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
>                                                         ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\BaseConfigurationsDao.java:11:
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object insertBaseConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:18:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer> p0);
>                                                               ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:17:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getAppConfigCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:17:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getAppConfigCount(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:23:
> error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be
> converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such
> type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.idware.uss.DataBase.DBModels.AppConfigurations> p0);
>                                                                                                ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:22:
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLatestAppConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:22:
> error: Unused parameter: p0
>     public abstract java.lang.Object getLatestAppConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:13:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
>                                                         ^E:\Repo\uss\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\reviewDebug\com\idware\uss\DataBase\DAO\AppConfigurationsDao.java:11:
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object insertAppConfig(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Even I update a couple of things but stacktrace remain same

**DAO's**

**NotificationsDao**

```
    @Dao
    interface NotificationsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertNotification(notification: Notification)

    @Query("SELECT * from notifications where type = 0 ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun getAllSubscriberNotifications(): LiveData<List<Notification>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notifications ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getLastNotification(): Notification?

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notifications WHERE type = 0 ")
    suspend fun getNotificationCount(): Int
}
```

**BaseConfigurationsDao**

```
    @Dao
    interface BaseConfigurationsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertBaseConfig(baseConfigurations: BaseConfigurations)


    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base_configurations")
    suspend fun getBaseConfigCount(): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM base_configurations WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM base_configurations) ")
    suspend fun getLatestBaseConfig(): BaseConfigurations?

    @Query("UPDATE base_configurations SET userEmail = :newEmail WHERE userEmail = :oldEmail")
    suspend fun updateBaseConfigurationsEmail(oldEmail: String, newEmail: String)
}
```

**AppConfigurationsDao**

```
    @Dao
    interface AppConfigurationsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertAppConfig(appConfigurations: AppConfigurations)

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_configurations")
    suspend fun getAppConfigCount(): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM app_configurations WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM app_configurations) ")
    suspend fun getLatestAppConfig(): AppConfigurations?
}
```

**Entities**

**Notification**

```
@Entity(tableName = DB_Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATIONS)
class Notification(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    val title: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "body")
    val body: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    val dateReceived: Date,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    val notificationType: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email")
    val notificationEmail: String,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int = 0
)
```

**BaseConfigurations**

```
@Entity(tableName = DB_Constants.TABLE_BASE_CONFIGURATIONS)
class BaseConfigurations(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "abc")
    val abc: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "xyz")
    val xyz: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Email")
    val Email: String,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int = 0
)
```

**AppConfigurations**

```
@Entity(tableName = DB_Constants.TABLE_APP_CONFIGURATIONS)
class AppConfigurations(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "brandingName")
    val brandingName: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "copyrightText")
    val copyrightText: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "bgColor")
    val bgColor: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "fontColor")
    val fontColor: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "logoUrl")
    val logoUrl: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Detail")
    val Detail: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Logo")
    val Logo: String?,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int = 0

)
```

**Converter**

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long): Date {
        return Date(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date): Long {
        return date.time
    }
}
```

**DB**

```
@Database(entities = [Notification::class, BaseConfigurations::class, 
AppConfigurations::class], version = DB_Constants.DB_VERSION)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AbcDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun notificationsDao(): NotificationsDao
    abstract fun baseConfigurationsDao(): BaseConfigurationsDao
    abstract fun appConfigurationsDao(): AppConfigurationsDao

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: USSDatabase

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): USSDatabase {
            if (::instance.isInitialized)
                return instance

            synchronized(this) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AbcDatabase::class.java,
                    DB_Constants.DB_NAME
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()

                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

In **AbcDatabase**, in the **companion object**, you are defining instance as a type of ***USSDatabase***, it should be **AbcDatabase**.

So **AbcDatabase** could be (commented out incorrect code left in ):-

```
@Database(entities = [Notification::class, BaseConfigurations::class,
    AppConfigurations::class], version = DB_Constants.DB_VERSION)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AbcDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun notificationsDao(): NotificationsDao
    abstract fun baseConfigurationsDao(): BaseConfigurationsDao
    abstract fun appConfigurationsDao(): AppConfigurationsDao

    companion object {
        //private lateinit var instance: USSDatabase
        private lateinit var instance: AbcDatabase

        //fun getDatabase(context: Context): USSDatabase {
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AbcDatabase {
            if (::instance.isInitialized)
                return instance

            synchronized(this) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AbcDatabase::class.java,
                    DB_Constants.DB_NAME
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()

                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue 2**

In **BaseConfigurationsDao** you are referring to a column named userEmail, the **BaseConfiguration** Entity uses `@ColumnInfo(name = "Email") val Email: String,`. i.e. the column name is **Email** not ***userEmail***.

So **BaseConfigurationsDao** could be :-

```
@Dao
interface BaseConfigurationsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertBaseConfig(baseConfigurations: BaseConfigurations)


    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base_configurations")
    suspend fun getBaseConfigCount(): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM base_configurations WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM base_configurations) ")
    suspend fun getLatestBaseConfig(): BaseConfigurations?

    /* Issue 1  column is not userEmail it is Email
    @Query("UPDATE base_configurations SET userEmail = :newEmail WHERE userEmail = :oldEmail")
    suspend fun updateBaseConfigurationsEmail(oldEmail: String, newEmail: String)
    */

    /* Fix 1 */
    @Query("UPDATE base_configurations SET Email = :newEmail WHERE Email = :oldEmail")
    suspend fun updateBaseConfigurationsEmail(oldEmail: String, newEmail: String)
}
```

- again incorrect code has been left in but commented out.

With the above changes the code that you have provided and a class DB_Constants as per:-

```
class DB_Constants {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NOTIFICATIONS: String = "notifications"
        const val TABLE_BASE_CONFIGURATIONS: String = "base_configurations"
        const val TABLE_APP_CONFIGURATIONS: String = "app_configurations"
        const val DB_VERSION: Int = 1
        const val DB_NAME: String = "abc.db"
    }
```

**then your code successfully compiles** as per :-

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project E:\AndroidStudioApps\SO69265290KotlinRoom

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
E:\AndroidStudioApps\SO69265290KotlinRoom\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\a\a\so69265290kotlinroom\AbcDatabase.java:8: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class AbcDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:compileDebugSources
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:assembleDebug

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
30 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 22 up-to-date

Build Analyzer results available

}
```

With a couple of tweaks to suit running on the main thread

- added .allowMainThreadQueries to database build
- removed suspend from dao's

and using the following code :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: AbcDatabase
    lateinit var notificationsDao: NotificationsDao
    lateinit var appConfigurationsDao: AppConfigurationsDao
    lateinit var baseConfigurationsDao: BaseConfigurationsDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = AbcDatabase.getDatabase(this)
        notificationsDao = db.notificationsDao()
        appConfigurationsDao = db.appConfigurationsDao()
        baseConfigurationsDao = db.baseConfigurationsDao()

        baseConfigurationsDao.insertBaseConfig(BaseConfigurations("abc1","xyz1","email1"))
        appConfigurationsDao.insertAppConfig(AppConfigurations("brand1","brand1 copyright","red","black","brand1 url","brand1 detail","brand1 logo"))
        notificationsDao.insertNotification(
            Notification("Notification1","body for notfication1",
                Date(),"type1","email1"))
        Log.d("BASECOUNT","Counts is ${baseConfigurationsDao.getBaseConfigCount()}")
        var  bc = baseConfigurationsDao.getLatestBaseConfig()
        baseConfigurationsDao.updateBaseConfigurationsEmail(bc!!.Email,bc!!.Email + " updated")
        Log.d("APPCOUNT","Count is ${appConfigurationsDao.getAppConfigCount()}")
        var ac = appConfigurationsDao.getLatestAppConfig()
        Log.d("NOTCOUNT","Count is ${notificationsDao.getNotificationCount()}")
        var n = notificationsDao.getLastNotification()
    }
}
```

The the code runs successfully and the log includes :-

```
2021-09-22 07:36:39.948 D/BASECOUNT: Counts is 1
2021-09-22 07:36:39.956 D/APPCOUNT: Count is 1
2021-09-22 07:36:39.960 D/NOTCOUNT: Count is 0
```

The resultant database, via Android Studio's App Inspector, is :-

[image]

and :-

[image]

- note that the email has been updated accordingly

and :-

[image]